# LDAP SASL Binding C++

Tags: c++, ldap

I'm currently implementing authorization mechanism on Linux against AD domain. I use for authorization the OpenLDAP library. Now I'm trying to perform the binding operation using `ldap_sasl_bind_s` function, and as the response from server my application is receiving the challenge but I'm not sure how to solve it. So I'm stuck with this:

```
berval creds;            // User creds
berval *srv = NULL;      // Server challenge
creds.bv_val = (char*)password.c_str();
creds.bv_len = password.length();

ret = ldap_sasl_bind_s(
        ldapConnection,
        username.c_str(),
        "DIGEST-MD5",
        &creds,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &srv
        );

if((srv != NULL) && (ret == LDAP_SASL_BIND_IN_PROGRESS)) // If challenge has been received
{
    // Challenge solving mechanism goes there.
    ret = ldap_sasl_bind_s(
        ldapConnection,
        username.c_str(),
        "DIGEST-MD5",
        srv, // Not sure if it's the right place
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
        );

    if(ret != LDAP_SUCCESS) // Here I get 0x31 (LDAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS)
    {
        ldap_unbind_ext(ldapConnection, NULL, NULL);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks to [IBM Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/apis/ldap_sasl_bind_s.htm) I figured how to bind credentials. Using simple auth mechanism we can do this by calling

```
ret = ldap_sasl_bind_s(
        ldapConnection,
        "username@example.com",
        NULL, // Simple bind mechanism
        &creds,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
        );
```